# Time mismatch in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I have set time zone as 'Asia/Calcutta' in administrator preferences. And create a message in `Whole company` group, then the time shows like 'less than a minute ago'. But in my website page it shows '6 hours ago'. How can i change it?.

[image]

**Website**

[image]

**OR**

How can i convert UTC time to local time in qweb?

Answer (score 0):

refer this link.Your problem will solve.

> https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-get-users-timezone-for-python-30906

and still, for the more R & D, you can go to

> https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html this link.